# Can't understand this Ruby Hashes num Code

Tags: ruby, hash

I don't understand the below Ruby code... Hope someone can explain.
When I type the below code

```
<% output = '    ' -%><br>
<% 10.downto(1) {|num| output << " RUBY#{num}"} -%><br>
<%= output -%><br>
```

it will show up on the browser as below;

```
RUBY10 RUBY9 RUBY8 RUBY7 RUBY6 RUBY5 RUBY4 RUBY3 RUBY2 RUBY1
```

I understand the part '10.downto(1)' means 10,9,8...1 counting down and '|num|' means number. But

1. what does '|num| output' mean?
2. why does the countdown number appear in the #{|num|}!?

I will understand if the code was

```
<% 10.downto(1) do |num| -%><br>
Ruby<%= num %><br>
```

and it gave back

```
Ruby10 Ruby9 Ruby8 Ruby7 Ruby6 Ruby5 Ruby4 Ruby3 Ruby2 Ruby1
```

Answer (score 1):

1) what does '|num| output' mean?

this doesn't mean anything.  ON the first line you declare that output is a string.  the << operator append the value to a string.  IN your case  " RUBY#{num}"  Is appendeds to the string.  at the end you return the string by calling output which returns the value of the string.

2) why does the countdown number appear in the #{|num|}!?

You interpolated the value.  Essentially you num represents a variable.  Each time the loop runs the variable changes and the "#{}" syntax says to use the variable value.

Answer (score 1):

- `10.downto(1)` returns an [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html), used to iterate over the range `[10, 1]`
- `{ ... }` is a *block*, or a "chunk" of code that can be passed around. See: [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Proc.html)
- `|num|` is a *parameter* of the block (the current number in this case)
- `output << ...` concatenates a value to the `output` String (roughly equivalent to `+=`). **[doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)**
- `"#{...}"` is *string interpolation*, the result of the code in between braces will be inserted into the final string.